# '\n' in `IFS=$'\n' is a variable?

Tags: bash

I notice that to set newline `IFS` should with a $ as prefix

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

but if set a colon, just

```
IFS=:
```

Is `\n` is a variable?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That `$'...'` in `bash` is not parameter expansion, it's a special kind of quote introduced by `ksh93` that expands those `\n`, `\x0a`, `\12` codes to a newline character. `zsh` also added `\u000a` / `\U0000000a` for the characters with the corresponding Unicode code point. `ksh93` and `bash` also have `\cj` while `zsh` has `\C-J`. `ksh93` also supports variations like `\x{a}`.

The `$` is a cue that it is some form or expansion. But in any case, it differs from other forms of expansions that use `$` (like `$((1 + 1))`, `$param` or `$(cmd)`) in that it is not performed inside double quotes or here documents (`echo "$'x'"` outputs `$'x'` in all shells though is unspecified per POSIX) and its expansion is not subject to split+glob, it's definitely closer to a quoting operator than an expansion operator.

`IFS=\n` would set IFS to `n` (`\` is treated as a quoting operator) and `IFS="\n"` or `IFS='\n'` would set IFS to the two characters backslash and `n`.

You can also use:

```
IFS='
'
```

or

```
IFS="
"
```

or

```
IFS=$'
'
```

To pass a literal newline, though that's less legible (and one can't see other than using things like `set list` in `vi` whether `$IFS` contains other spacing characters in that code).

`IFS=:`, `IFS=':'`, `IFS=":"`, `IFS=$':'` all set IFS to `:` so it doesn't matter which you use.

`$'...'` is supported (with variations) by at least: `ksh93`, `zsh`, `bash`, `mksh` , busybox `sh`, FreeBSD `sh`. `ksh93` and `bash` also have a `$"..."` form of quotes used for localisation of text though it's rarely used as it's cumbersome to deploy and use portably and reliably.

The `es` and `fish` shells can also use `\n` outside of quotes to expand to newline.

Some tools like `printf`, some implementations of `echo` or `awk` can also expand those `\n` by themselves. For instance, one can do:

```
printf '\n'
awk 'BEGIN{printf "\n"}'
echo
echo '\n\c' # UNIX compliant echos only
```

to output of newline character, but note that:

```
IFS=$(printf '\n')
```

won't work because command substitution (`$(...)`) strips all trailing newline characters. You can however use:

```
eval "$(printf 'IFS="\n"')"
```

Which works because the output of `printf` ends in a `"` character, not a newline.

Now, for completeness, in the `rc` shell and derivatives (like `es` or `akanga`), `$'\n'` is indeed the expansion of that `\n` variable (a variable whose name is the sequence of two characters `\` and `n`). Those shells don't have a limitation on what characters variable names may contain and only have one type of quotes: `'...'`.

```
$ rc
; '\n' = (foo bar)
; echo $'\n'
foo bar
; echo $'\n'(1)
foo
```

`rc` variables are also all exported to the environment, but at least in the Unix variant of `rc`, for variable names like `\n`, the environment variable version undergoes a form of encoding:

```
; env | grep foo | sed -n l
__5cn=foo\001bar$
```

(`0x5c` being the byte value of ASCII `\`; see also how that array variable was encoded with a 0x1  byte as the separator).

Comment: `+1` for the usual inhuman level of knowledge

Answer (score 10):

This is [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

> Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially. The word expands to `string`, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

Thus `$'\n'` is replaced by a newline.

This is unrelated to [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), despite the use of `$`.

Answer (score 6):

Strings like `$'\n'` have been introduced by `ksh93` and are currently not part of the POSIX standard.

They allow to use most C alike escapes, e.g. `$'\u2345'` and the escapes that are also supported by `echo`.

Note that if you do not like (in case of ksh93 or bash) to use that escape method, you still may use:

```
IFS='
'
```

which is equivalent but harder to read.

BTW: This extension already has passed the POSIX standard commitee, but it is scheduled for **SUSv8** that is expected to appear not before the year 2020 because we first need to work on our lag behind the current list of bugs.

Comment: The `$'...'` expansions differ from that of `echo`. They're more like the ones for the format argument of `printf`. For `echo`, a 0 is required in `\0123` while for `$'...'` and `printf` format, `\0123` would be `\012` a newline followed by a litteral 3.

Comment: Note that the `$'...'` specification is still being discussed. There are several issues still to be resolved with the currently proposed wording.

Comment: IIRC, It was closed but has been reopened. Due to the fact that there is still plenty of time before it becomes effective, I don't see a real problem with that.

Comment: It was closed, I raised several objections, it was reopen, it was then amended,  there are still several problems (most of them about `\uxxxx` expansion), and no resolution in sight that would  accommodate existing implementations. So it may not make it into the next POSIX version. Maybe they could leave the `\uxxxx` expansion out for issue8, so we can still have at least `$'\n'`.